# Mac/iPhone:Streaming video file to iPhone

Tags: iphone, macos

I have a http streaming link which gives me .flv streaming feed. I want to convert that and access in my iPhone program. How can i do that? I want to have a desktop software like VLC and input this streaming feed URL and convert to iPhone supported and stream again to iPhone. I tried VLC with H.264 and Mpeg-1 audio, but seems to be it doesn't give the supported format, so as iPhone program doesn't play the video. 
Could someone please guide me how can i setup a desktop software which can stream iPhone supported file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a job for superuser.com!

Comment: You might be stuck restricting this feature to WiFi only since it is tricky to get a streaming video application approved otherwise, just as a heads up.

Comment: No problems for now. I can later make my connection public. If it works for now atleast only within Wifi is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think even the great VLC can't convert FLV on the fly...(or even do anything with FLV). As far as streaming goes, you'll probably be limited to the local network (Wi-Fi). I'd start with the simple way—create an ad-hoc file server on the desktop, then use AVPlayer's initWithURL method to find that video.

On the desktop, you could query the IP address of the computer, and ask the user to enter that URL (along with an optional port assignment and file component, like http://192.168.0.2:2234/streamingVideo.mp4) onto the iDevice, then convert to NSURL.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But i have some doubts. Please guide me. Step 1: Create ad-hoc file server on desktop -> How can i do that? Any sample server that you could think of? Does it going to store my .flv stream to desktop somewhere? Step 2: Use AVPlayer initwithURL to find the video -> Do you mean this should be on my iPhone app? If yes, why?  Step 3: ask the user to enter that URL onto the iDevice  -> Does it mean if i enter my computer IP as url on the iPhone program, would that be able to steam the video and play?

Comment: I'm actually not sure about the ad-hoc file server part...the desktop environment is not my forte. But basically, I was thinking along the lines of having the user enter an address, like 192.168.2:2234/video.mp4 into the iDevice, and then load it with AVPlayer's initWithURL—Yes to your last question. Yes, use initWithURL (the user entered URL) on the iDevice to load the resource.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the http streaming link? This matters a lot as in order to stream to the iPhone you need to use HTTP Live Streaming which requires some different bits than a typical flash media, or more properly RTMP, server. Typically you need two different streaming architectures or some expensive boxes.